# Simualtion stops at time 0 after a real to real multiplication!

Tags: vhdl, simulation

In my project, which compiles fine on ModelSim, when I try to simulate my code it gives me:
[image: simulation log]

Here is my code for multiplier:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.MATH_REAL.ALL;

ENTITY mult IS
    PORT(
        a, b: IN REAL;
        dataOut: OUT REAL
    );
END mult;

ARCHITECTURE base OF mult IS
BEGIN
    dataOut <= a * b;
END base;
```

and this is my memory which derives a and b:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.MATH_REAL.ALL;

ENTITY memory IS
    GENERIC(
        memCapacity: INTEGER := 8
    );
    PORT(
      w, r: IN BIT;
      address: IN INTEGER;
      dataIn: IN REAL;
      dataOut: OUT REAL
    );
END memory;

ARCHITECTURE base OF memory IS
TYPE memBlock IS ARRAY (INTEGER RANGE <>) OF REAL;
SIGNAL mem: memBlock(memCapacity DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    PROCESS (w, r)
    BEGIN
        IF (w = '1') THEN
            mem(address) <= dataIn;
        ELSIF (r = '1') THEN
            dataOut <= mem(address);
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END base;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was kinda weird. At last, I drived 1.0 on my memories output all the time; so now, the unit is completely out of circuit and it is only a wire connected to 1.0. But it couldn't solve it either. Then I declared default values for all my signals but it still wasn't helpful. Then I changed my code of multiplier to this code:

```
BEGIN
PROCESS
BEGIN
  wait for 0 ns;
  dataOut <= a * b;
  wait on a, b;
END PROCESS;
END base;
```

It works while logically it's the same as the previous code.

Comment: A default value to a port of mode in is used when there is no other driving value. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.2 Driving values para 3 e). "If S is a basic signal: — If S has no source, then the driving value of S is given by the default value associated with S (see 6.4.2.3)." It's the actual that wants to have the an initial value. Note Brian's answer writes of the testbench declarations where the actuals of a and b would be found. The same holds true for addition.

Answer (score 1):

Your simulation is probably working correctly though unless you post an [MCVE] we can't be completely be sure..

```
TYPE memBlock IS ARRAY (INTEGER RANGE <>) OF REAL;
SIGNAL mem: memBlock(memCapacity DOWNTO 0);
```

There are no initial values specified for the contents of mem, so each value in the array is initialised to the default, which is `REAL'LEFT`, or a rather large negative number.

Presumably your testbench initialises the values on ports `a` and `b` the same way. Multiplying them together will give an extremely large positive number, with the result shown.

You can initialise signals in the declaration, for example,

```
SIGNAL a_test, b_test : REAL := 0.0;
SIGNAL mem: memBlock(memCapacity DOWNTO 0) := (others => 0.0);
```

will clear the array's contents, as well as the `a_test` signal(etc)  you connect up to ports `a` and `b` in your testbench.